# How to create a sliding window in R to divide data into test and train samples to test accuracy of forecasts?

Tags: r, forecasting

We are using the `forecast` package in R to read 3 weeks worth of hourly data (3*7*24 data points) and make predictions for the next 24 hours. It's a time-series with multiple seasonality.

We have the forecast model running just fine and it seems to be doing well. Now, we wish to quantify the accuracy of our approach / forecasting algorithm for our data. We wish to use the `accuracy` function in `forecast` package for this purpose. We understand that the `accuracy` function works so that it `f` is the forecast and `x` is the actual observation vector then `accuracy(f,x)` would give us the several accuracy measurements for this forecast.

We have data from the past several months and we wish to write a sliding window algorithm that picks (3*7*24) hour values and then predicts the next 24 hours. Then, compares these values against actual data for the next day / 24 hours, displays the accuracy, then slides the window by (24 points / hours) / next day and repeats.

The sample data is generated as follows:

```
library("forecast")

time <- 1:(12*168)
set.seed(1)
ds <- msts(sin(2*pi*time/24)+c(1,1,1.2,0.8,1,0,0)[((time-1)%/%24)%%7+1]+ time/400+rnorm(length(time),0,0.2),seasonal.periods=c(24,168))
plot(ds)
head(ds)
tail(ds)
length(ds)
length(time)
```

Forecasting procedure is as follows:

```
model <- tbats(ds[1:504])
fcst <- forecast(model,h=24,level=90)
accuracy(fcst,ds[505:528])     ##Test accuracy of forecast against next/actual 24 values
```

Now, we wish to slide the "window" by 24 and repeat the same procedure, that is, the next set of values used to build the model will be `ds[25:528]` and their accuracy will be tested against `ds[529:552]` ... and so on. How can we implement this?

Also, is there a better way to test overall accuracy of this forecasting algorithm for our scenario?

Comment: You should look into caret's timeslice cross validation: https://rpubs.com/crossxwill/time-series-cv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by creating a vector of times representing the front edge of the sliding windows, then using `lapply` to iterate the forecasting and scoring process over the windows those edges imply. Like...

```
# set a couple of parameters we'll use to slice the series into chunks:
# window width (w) and the time step at which you want to end the first
# training set
w = 24 ; start = 504

# now use those parameters to make a vector of the time steps at which each
# window will end
steps <- seq(start + w, length(ds), by = w)

# using lapply, iterate the forecasting-and-scoring process over the
# windows that created
cv_list <- lapply(steps, function(x) {

    train <- ds[1:(x - w)] 
    test <- ds[(x - w + 1):x]

    model <- tbats(train)
    fcst <- forecast(model, h = w, level = 90)
    accuracy(fcst, test)

})
```

Example output for the first window:

```
> cv_list[[1]]
                       ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE     MAPE      MASE
Training set 0.0001587681 0.3442898 0.2689754 34.3957362 84.30841 0.9560206
Test set     0.2619029897 0.8961109 0.7868256 -0.6832273 36.64301 2.7966186
                   ACF1
Training set 0.02588145
Test set             NA
```

If you want summaries of the scores for the whole list, you can do something like...

```
rmse <- mean(unlist(lapply(cv_list, '[[', "Test set","RMSE")))
```

...which produces this:

```
[1] 1.011177
```

Comment: Thank you. Executing the function `lapply` to get `cv_list` is taking too long to process. The total length of `ds` is 2016 and it should not take very long. I'm not able to obtain accuracy results on screen since it seems to be stuck in a loop.

Comment: Also, `start` should be `1` I believe since we are starting to train the model using values `1` to `504` in the first round.

Comment: The process isn't stuck in a loop; it just takes a long time to estimate that many `tbats` models.( I didn't benchmark it, but the process completed on my laptop. If you want to speed it up, you might try using `foreach` instead.) And, no, the way it's written, you don't want to start at 1. Take a look at how `train` is created inside the call to `lapply` and you'll (hopefully) see what I mean.

Comment: You're right, I let it run for a while and it does complete execution. One last question about the last step: does it make sense to take mean of `MAPE` or `RMSE`, for example, to express overall error produced by the model on different data sets of same type?

Comment: That's a methods question, not a coding one, so probably best asked on Cross Validated if you want advice on it. Another option here, though, would be to aggregate the forecasts and observed values for each window in `lapply`, then combine those chunks and do your scoring at the end on the whole thing. This is akin to what you'd do with one-step-ahead forecasting.

Comment: I guess I will ask that on cross-validated. Meanwhile, I noticed there's a difference between my RMSE mean and yours. Mine is: `> rmse
[1] 0.876232`. Shouldn't they be the same since I set the data seed to `1`?